Is it correct to say "the hem came unsewn"?

(source)
The thread of my hem of my Tshirt got broken and a short part of the hem is unsewn.
Is it correct to say:?
the hem came undone
the hem came unsewn
the hem is falling apart.

[correction: the thread of the hem in my t-shirt]. Hems becomes undone.  unravel is usually for wool thread in sweaters.

Came undone and came unsewn are both OK - fall apart usually implies breaking into pieces. (I think we all know what an unravelled thread looks like!)

You can say "came unsewn." It is idiomatic and well attested.

The hem of her long dress came unsewn as soon as they got out of the station.


Well attested? Your own Google Books link says No results found for "hem came unsewn". But there's more that a pageful of results for "hem came undone"

There's one right there: " ... hem of her long dress came unsewn as soon as they got out of the station". Also "come unsewn" and "coming unsewn" are well attested.

That's as may be. But I followed your link, and at the top it says No results found for "hem came unsewn".
Results for hem came unsewn (without quotes): Nothing like that when I searched for undone.

The point is, "to come unsewn" is well established, and the various forms (came unsewn, is | was coming unsewn, etc) are attested.

The idiomatic standard is...

The hem came undone (about a dozen hits in Google Books)

Note that although it will obviously be understood, Google Books reports no hits at all for the highlighted 3-word sequence in...

The hem came unsewn (link)


It may be worth noting that if a hem "comes undone", that can only really mean the stitching has "unraveled" (hems don't usually have buttons). Whereas...

His shirt came undone (link)

...is more likely to mean the shirt buttons came undone, rather than the stitching. But obviously you can say My shirt stitching is coming undone.

The other two sentences are correct.  But this one sounds wrong

the hem came unsewn

If you really must use this construct then it should be

the hem became unsewn


"came unsewn" is idiomatic. https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=b2e9466f8d6921f5&sca_upv=1&sxsrf=ADLYWIKFQGhg9ddXDD78TGfdhIYHgtCt3g:1715695934767&q=%22hem+came+unsewn%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivnsmbtz&sa=X&biw=1448&bih=895&dpr=1.1
